# Wiki App doesn't install with newer Sharepoint UI style

Tags: wiki-pages, sharepoint-server

I've been doing some tests on Sharepoint online and noticed that if I install a Wiki App I can see a new UI in Sharepoint that allows me to easily add new sections and web parts to the page as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I tried a similar thing by installing the Wiki App in my local Sharepoint Server (on premises). I went to my team site --> Add new app --> Wiki page library. When I tried to add a new page after installing the Wiki app, it still shows the old Sharepoint UI:

[image]

Is there a server update or something I'm missing that I need to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wiki pages app (at this time) will always have the Classic UI. The Modern UI for pages only applies to the Pages Library.

Based on searching for `wiki` on [the Roadmap](https://products.office.com/en-US/business/office-365-roadmap?filters=%26freeformsearch=wiki) there doesn't appear to be a current plan to implement modern pages to the wiki app.

Comment: So I assume then that in general, modern UI is not available for Sharepoint on premises?

Comment: Based on https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Modern-Page-Experience-availability-in-SharePoint-2016-On-Prem/td-p/110099 it appears that you are correct, modern UI is *not* available for on-prem